# How add SWI-Prolog terminal in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, swi-prolog

How can an SWL-Prolog terminal be added in VSCode?

Like PowerShell but SWI-Prolog terminal.

Comment: Great question, perhaps you should also join the [SWI-Prolog forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/)

Comment: You want to build a shell with swi-prolog running (instead of power-shell, with DOS/Windows interpretor running) ?

This is already what you get when you install swi-prolog in Windows. You can use swi-prolog settings to pre-load your application, and even start your code to have some menu etc. Otherwise, you have to hack into the swi-prolog source codes to personnalize even further the shell.

Answer (score 10):

To create an SWI-Prolog terminal within Visual Studio Code, the process is the same as starting an SWI-Prolog terminal from a DOS prompt but you just start by creating an initial terminal in VSC.

1. Using VSC menu `Terminal` > `New Terminal`
   or `` Ctrl+Shift+` ``
2. Start SWI-Prolog from the command line using `swipl`

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.685]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Groot>swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.3.8)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit https://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).     

1 ?-
```

---

If you have an existing terminal open and want to add another terminal then in the upper right of the terminal

[image]

click on `+` and then at the command prompt `>` enter `swipl`.

Your terminal selector will now have an added `swipl` option.

[image]